# 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'- How do I solve this error regarding combinations of values?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I have created a Visual Studio application using ASP.NET and WPF connected to a MSSQL database/server for keeping track of how long someone takes on some other desktop application. There is a page where the user can enter information of what app they accessed, what sort of app it is, and **when they accessed and closed it**, and I am having trouble with inputting the DateTime values into my database. As per the DateTime format, I have tried to combine a date from a DatePicker with a time from textboxes in the form (both values are in the DateTime format, but I take their separate components and combine them).

The error I got (from debugging using the VS debugger) is: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime", at:

```
combinedStart = DateTime.ParseExact(startString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

..and the next line too.

For further information, I combine the values from **textboxes** (to get the **hour and minute values**), **ComboBoxes** (for **'AM'** or **'PM'**), and **DatePickers** (for the **dates**). The expected result is the inputting of the DateTime values in the exact same format as in the above line of code. Could someone suggest something to solve this problem? Please consider that I am new to C# and WPF in general, along with posting questions in StackOverflow.

The full C# code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using TimeOrganiser.Properties;

namespace TimeOrganiser
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    String startDate;
    String endDate;
    String startString;
    String endString;
    DateTime combinedStart;
    DateTime combinedEnd;          
    double DurationHrs;
    
    public Window2()
    {
        
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //...

    private void btnAdd_Entry(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String cnString = Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(cnString);
        ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)cbxAppType.SelectedItem;
        String selectedText = selectedItem.Content.ToString();
        ComboBoxItem selectedItem2 = (ComboBoxItem)cbxAMPM.SelectedItem;
        String selectedText2 = selectedItem2.Content.ToString();
        ComboBoxItem selectedItem3 = (ComboBoxItem)cbxEndAMPM.SelectedItem;
        String selectedText3 = selectedItem3.Content.ToString();

        startString = startDate + " " + txtStartTimeHr.Text + ":" + txtStartTimeMin.Text + ":" + "00 " + selectedText2;
        endString = endDate + " " + txtEndTimeHr.Text + ":" + txtEndTimeMin.Text + ":" + "00 " + selectedText3;
        combinedStart = DateTime.ParseExact(startString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        combinedEnd = DateTime.ParseExact(endString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //combinedStart = DateTime.Parse(startString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //combinedEnd = DateTime.Parse(endString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        //combinedStart = new DateTime();
        DurationHrs = (combinedEnd - combinedStart).TotalHours; 

        try
        {
            String sqlGetPassQuery = "INSERT INTO ApplicationInfo (AppName, " +
                "StartDate, EndDate, DurationHrs, Productivity, Entertainment, Social, Browsing) " +
                "Values (@AppName, @StartDate, @EndDate, @DurationHrs, ";

            //...other unrelated code

            sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }

    private void StartDate_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (clnStartDate.SelectedDate.HasValue)
        {
            startDate = clnStartDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
            
        }
    }

    private void EndDate_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (clnEndDate.SelectedDate.HasValue)
        {
            endDate = clnEndDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
           
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's a specific value of `startString` that fails for you?

Comment: My guess is you are inputting single digits like `5` for the hour but specifying `hh` which doesn't match.

Comment: use parse(ur data here) instead of parseExact

Comment: Try adding `.PadLeft(2, '0')` after the `txtStartTimeHr.Text` and `txtStartTimeMin.Text`

Comment: Why not create a new date from your parts using this constructor? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the problem, thanks to @Ahmed Alayat's suggestion. The solution to this was:

```
combinedStart = DateTime.Parse(startString);
combinedEnd = DateTime.Parse(endString);
```

Comment: Solution is:   
`combinedStart = DateTime.Parse(startString);
combinedEnd = DateTime.Parse(endString);`
I'm trying to follow the conventions from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat, but how do I make an answer Community Wiki? Also, I can only accept my own answer tomorrow.

Comment: This is a terrible solution, as it relies on your default machine settings. It would be better to understand what the exact raw text is so that you can explicitly parse it.

Comment: I understand, but at this point I do not require a perfect solution. This is for an assignment, so due to time constraints, just a working solution would have to suffice.

Comment: It's a fragile working solution that could change if your environment changes. It's bad programming practice. All you would need to do to fix this properly is show us the string that was failing and we could give you an answer in less than 30 seconds. You've spent way too much time and you've come up with poor solution.